# Warm Start of Cache

Tags: ignite

1.While priming a ignite cache, what is the performance when its done from persistent store? What is the preferred method of priming a cache on warm start ? Is there any way it can be done by taking a file dump and then priming the cache ,which would be faster then doing it from Persistent Store?

2.How are the indexes built if a ignite server goes down ?

3.If its rebuilt then is there any way by which we can avoid this overhead? Off heap storage would be comparitively slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are two ways to load large amounts of data from the persistence store: using `IgniteDataStreamer` and through `CacheStore` implementation. Please refer to [1] for details. `CacheStore` can be more performant, especially with partition-aware approach, but `IgniteDataStreamer` can be also used to continuously stream the data while executing other cache operations concurrently. Dumping to a file is not supported by Ignite, but there is an enterprise-level feature provided by GridGain that does this [2].
2. Indexes are not rebuilt in this case. If you have backups, indexes are maintained for them as well as for primary entries, so if node fails, nothing is lost.
3. As I mentioned in 2, indexes are not rebuilt in case of node failure.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading

[2] https://gridgain.readme.io/docs/local-recoverable-store

Comment: I have presently implemented a cachestore loadcache to do a warm start but again its from a persistent store ,which may not be the fastest way to prime a cache.

Comment: Are the indexes 'duplicated' in all backups across all nodes inorder to avoid scanning of indexes and then getting to know which all indexes belong to the particular node?

Comment: Yes, indexes are duplicated in order to support failover. If a node fails, you don't lose data as well as indexes for this data.